# Read multiple csv files in pandas data frame assigning addionall default value for each file

Tags: python, pandas

i want to ask how is possible while you are reading 50 csv files (with one row) to one pandas data frame to assign a second row with different value(default) for each of those csvs

Comment: can you post a sample content of one of those CSV files?

Comment: 15 Days to #Trump : Counting down to Inauguration Day and @DaysOfTrump in the White House! #MakeAmericaGreatAgain. all of them are tweets